# Horizontal scaling in traditional RDBMSs

Tags: nosql, rdbms, horizontal-scaling

I just came across NoSQL systems with all their godsent advantages. One of them seems to be effortless horizontal scaling. My question is, why isn't a classical RDBMS like MySQL or SQL Server, capable of horizontal scaling? Or incapable of doing it to the same extent as NoSQL systems?

Comment: NoSQL systems solve much simpler problems. For example, no joins or no indexes.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons. Here is one:

Horizontal scaling is usually achieved by sharding - a given entity is stored on one host in a cluster, decided by some function of that entity. Joins across shards are extremely inefficient, if possible at all. Traditional RDBMS rely on data which can be joined being collocated, which often prevents effective sharding.

Comment: It's certainly possible as rethinkdb (NoSQL) implements joins. If you're sharding in such a way these joins are likely to be on the same shard the performance isn't terribly affected. One extra problem for RDBMS' though is each shard _must_ have the same schema's otherwise things will get weird. Triggers would also be extremely challenging to implement in a sharded enviorment

Answer (score 0):

I take a different stub at it from @joews.

Some scenarios require full-text search. Or store some key-value data of high volumes. Some NoSQL systems, like Lucene for example, have several type of indices that can be scanned in parallel (think about it). Whereas traditional RDBMS search using one index at a time or some times even default to expensive full table scans.

Some companies, like Facebook, have sharded MySQL instances for live content serving. But to make this possible you might need to venture into things like changing MySQL source code and / or building systems on top of it. Are you sure you are ready for this?

Other use cases have so much data, that it just does not fit into the querying model of traditional RDBMS, this is why all sorts of systems, like Dremel, Apache Drill and Presto arise.

All this said, remember about the fact, that NoSQL systems group into buckets depending on how they address the famous CAP theorem. The simplest explanation to my taste was given by Martin Fowler: in the presence of network partitioning for a distributed system you can either guarantee data consistency (no conflicts between different user interactions with the system) or system availability (system is searchable or data is accepted no matter etc). I highly recommend to watch this Introduction to NoSQL by Martin: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qI_g07C_Q5I

In contrast, RDBMS are transactional, i.e. they provide all or nothing functionality, like ATM machines. If it is something that is acceptable for your use case and volumes of usage / data, use it! If not, look towards NoSQL, but study the landscape and find the best option.

Answer (score 0):

There're two point of views of horizontal scaling:

1) You have too much data and one single RDBMS node cannot afford it => sharding

2) You want scale to many concurrent users => replication

Case 1) is hard because conventional JOINs don't work

Case 2) is not that hard, there're clustering options or you can make your own "clustering" approach in Java using JTA, take a look to this [article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/horizontal-scaling-rdbms-jta) it is based on [JEPLayer](https://code.google.com/p/jeplayer/) but other persistent ORMs could be used instead

Of course your problem could be the sum of 1) and 2)